# TODO comments in rStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, comments, todo

is there a way to list ToDo comments in rstudio?
Before I used eclipse and really loved to put some `# TODO I definitely need more unit tests here!` comments in my source code.

I could not find this feature in rStudio so far and I was wondering, if there is something like a plugin or maybe an easy way of searching such comments.

Comment: Why not directly asking to RStudio? https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us

Comment: Thanks for the link. I checked and two years ago, already some people asked for it. It looks like nothing changed since now. I am wondering, how other user deal with these things. I think it is pretty common in other IDEs. There is no plugin system in rstudio, is there?

Comment: Why don't you use `Ctrl+Shift+C` to insert comment you call `TODO`, then `Ctrl+F` to find `TODO`?

Comment: Nice suggestion, but might be a bit difficult in package development with 20 files. I might go with my command line solution `find . -type f -name '*.R' -exec grep -Hni 'todo' {} \;` but I thought there might be better solutions...

Comment: Use ctrl-shift-R (or cmd-shift-R on OS X) to insert a "section" comment which should show up in the RStudio function selector popup. Stick "TODO" in there and it shld be easy to find in-file.

Comment: Just installed RStudio version 1.1.423 and it looks like they've implemented a feature that changes the text color of 'TODO' and 'FIXME' keywords in code comments.

Comment: They really need to add more than those 2....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no such system in RStudio, but there is an easy way of searching for the comments. Do this:

1. Go to Edit -> Find in Files
2. Tick the checkbox "Regular Expression"
3. Enter the following regular expression: `^\s*# TODO`
4. Click Find

That regular expression will match any line that starts with `# TODO`.

Comment: Uh wow, haven't seen this option before... Great, I also can click the file name and also directly the lines where the comment is... Almost perfect! :-) Thanks for this hint.

Comment: It's odd that RStudio uses special syntax highlighting for #TODO yet doesn't seem to have any other built in functionality around them.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the regular expression (regex) [only if you really want to show results in which the search is starting a line]. And if you use the regex described above, you'll loose the possibility to add the comment anywhere, e.g. after another comment. In fact, I would not even include the #. Just find in files, TODO or FIXME :-)

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest that you consider the [`todor`](https://github.com/dokato/todor) RStudio add-in by [dokato](https://github.com/dokato). After installing via `devtools`:

```
devtools::install_github("dokato/todor")
```

You will be able to conveniently list ToDo items across your project:

[image: sourcing]

[image: Official example]

*(images and code sourced from: https://github.com/dokato/todor)*

Comment: Thanks for that comment. I vaguely remember reading that it will be implemented in rStudio in the near future anyways, together with some other keywords like `FIXME` or so... But I couldn't find the article at the moment. I will have a look into the package, but so far the `find in files` is very convenient. :-)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the outline list by having:

```
# TODO I definitely need more unit tests here! ####
```

Just keep in mind that you have to have 4 '#' at the end of the line

Comment: thanks, that's how i use it too. In case this is relevant for anybody else, it's possible to use four dashes `-` as an alternative to the four hashtags

Answer (score 5):

If you work with git and the files are tracked you can use

```
git grep TODO
```

in the terminal (which is also included in the Rstudio IDE) to get a list of your TODOs.