# Rstudio: Setting TO DOs

Tags: r, rstudio

How do I use TO DOs in RStudio? By TO DOs I mean, some special flags or comments that would stand out, so I could get back to certain things I want to rework/modify etc.

I searched on Internet as well as on Rstudio, but I don't seem to be able to find such a functionality as other IDEs have (e.g. `PyCharm` when I code in python). I am using comments currently, but that is very imperfect in a bigger project that is heavily commented anyway.

Can you share your tips and tricks?

Comment: Do you have a small screenshot of what you call "to do" in PyCharm. I don't see what you mean.

Comment: @Pascal This is a common feature in IDEs. Eclipse also handles this. In a C/C++ code you can write `/* ToDo ... */` and the IDE recognizes this, listing all these tasks in a clickable console window, allowing you to move directly to that part of the code. I don't think that anything similar is implemented in RStudio.

Comment: I guess currently you will have to wait until the right RStudio Add-in comes along - awesome new feature these "Add-ins" ... I am sure it is already somewhere in the making. Maybe you wanna take that road?

Comment: @RHertel  Sorry, I never coded in C/C++ so I don't know what it is.

Comment: @Pascal No need to be sorry for not coding in C/C++  :-) It was just an example for something I'm using rather often. I hope that my comment did not annoy you, and that it helped clarifying what it was about.

Comment: @RHertel   No problem. In long code, I create section in RStudio with a title, so I can reduce each block and reduce the length of the display. And easily navigate to sections.

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought that it isnt implemented yet. I will have to wait until the "Add-ins" then ;)  

@RHertel, do you use comments for this in Rstudio? or maybe some other tricks?

Comment: @WD11, I checked out the Addins, they look great. That is going to add a ton of productivity. Thanks for pointing them out, did not know about it before ;) now, the worst part...the waiting

Comment: @SpaceGr4vy Sorry, I did not see your question in the comment sooner (I didn't receive a notification, probably due to the comma that you placed after my ID). No, I'm not using any particular trick. But when it is possible, I like to split large code into different scripts, with one "main" file sourcing other scripts; almost like function calls. Since I cannot pass data easily from one script to another, I usually store the required data in temporary files; written by one script and read by another. This slows down the program, so I do this only for large and self-contained chunks of code.

Comment: @RHertel Thanks, for your answer. That is probably a good way to go. I will need to break my code up as well. It's only a dissertation but it is getting bigger and bigger ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + R to create a section label that stands out. Any code that sits between this and another section label can be minimized/maximized when you need to, and you can call it TO DO.

You can also use Alt + Shift + J to jump between these section labels when you want to rework or modify them.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31956142/2779245) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874127/todo-comments-in-rstudio) might help, I suppose.

I am not sure if it is okay to copy the full text of that answer, so briefly:

- `Shift` + `Cmd` + `F` / `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `F`
- enter `^\s*# TODO`:

  - `^` means the start of the string we are interested in,
  - `\s` is for any whitespace character (space, tab, line break),
  - and the following `*` implies that the whitespace character is repeated zero to an infinite amount of times;
- a-a-and – run the search!